# How to declare a relative path in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

I have this solution in visual studio

```
MicrosoftVisualStudioSolution //being click to open solution
MainfolderSolution
-Model
---Sample.model
-Scripts
---Index.js
-Contents
---text.json
```

Code from my Sample.model

```
    {
        try
        {
            string temp = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\Contents\text.json"); 
            string Data = File.ReadAllText(temp);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that it can't find text.json

Comment: Try `string temp = @"..\Contents\text.json";`

Comment: Path.Combine can't handle relative paths...

Comment: @tchelidze still now working

Comment: @123456 On a folder structure, where is placed your `exe` file ?

Comment: you mean the microsoft visual studio solution?

Comment: @123456 no, in your question you have written folder structure of you solution, i want to know where is `exe` file, which actually executes ? (somewhere in `Debug` folder).

Comment: Instead solution, you need output folder structure.

Comment: @tchelidze: it's a web application (see tags), thus, there is no "executable" file (web server executable doesn't count). But you're right in sense, that OP needs to build path, depending on project's output.

Comment: There is no debug folder

Comment: Can you use `var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/test.json");`

Comment: @Dennis Thanks dennis, i just noticed.

Comment: Thanks guys, especially to @ramiramilu :) your answer is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use -

```
var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/test.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

**For an example** let's see the below code to point crystal report template position 
string crysRTFReport = Server.MapPath(@"~\Reports\rptRTF_19.rpt");

Now if the file path is like this "C:\Crystal\BankAcc\ERP\Reports\rptRTF_19.rpt" and by mistake if you miss something then it will throw exception and to avoid the full string deceleration and safe typing we use @ before and the string folder\filename.filetype.